# Snowflake parse_json on varchar column seeing error JSON: unknown keyword "None"

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've ingested into a table the following rows in varchar column `breakdown` :

```
[{'platform': 'facebook', 'total': 20701, 'likes': 10106, 'shares': 3774, 'comments': 6168, 'tweets': None, 'favorites': None, 'hahas': 375, 'wows': 164, 'loves': 31, 'sads': 21, 'angrys': 62}]

[{'platform': 'facebook', 'total': 15958, 'likes': 7206, 'shares': 2931, 'comments': 541, 'tweets': None, 'favorites': None, 'hahas': 62, 'wows': 852, 'loves': 145, 'sads': 1968, 'angrys': 2253}]
```

When I try to do this to break out each dictionary into its own column I see this error:

```
with org_table as (
  select
loaded_date,
parse_json(breakdown) as CUSTOM_FIELDS
from my_table)
select
CUSTOM_FIELDS:platform::string as platform
from org_table
```

> Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "None", pos 107

Is there something I can change when creating the table file format to help with this? Below is the file format I have for this table:

```
    "type": 'csv',
    "field_delimiter": ',',
    "EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL": True,
    'escape_unenclosed_field': None,
    'date_format': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    'skip_header': 1,
    'escape': 'None',
    'FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY': '"',
    'error_on_column_count_mismatch': False,
    'NULL_IF': ('NULL', '', ' ', 'NULL', 'NULL', '//N', '\\N'),
    'RECORD_DELIMITER': '\n'
```

Comment: 2 things: why are you using a varchar instead of a variant column to ingest your JSON?  You could try to add 'None' to your `NULL_IF` statement, but I don't think that will help you in this case, since the value is embedded in your JSON.  You may need to replace that with a valid value or NULL.

Comment: Confirmed in the documentation that the `NULL_IF` won't help you unless you are flattening the data during load using the `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME` option.  It's sort of odd that you are getting JSON data with NONE as a value.  Why bother even including the element in the JSON if the value is essentially a NULL?

Comment: @MikeWalton I could not load the data when I had it set to a variant column, I kept seeing the error Error Parsing Json .... etc. as well.

Comment: You can test this somewhere like jsonlint.com. This is not valid JSON. The single quotes need to be double quotes. Also, as @MikeWalton mentioned, `None` isn't a valid value in JSON. It should be `"None"` as a double-quoted string, `0` as a number, or `null` (case sensitive without quotes). You'll have to fix the JSON structure either inside or outside of Snowflake before flattening / parsing using Snowflake semi-structured functions.

Comment: Thank you both,  I'm going to change it before loading then